# Not able to do SCP in SSH

Tags: python, ssh, scp

Here I'm providing complete details with script etails:

I'm running my script in HUB1.

Firstly,asking users for credentials like username,password,filename,path.

Sample Snipet:

```
try:
    usrname = raw_input('Enter your credentials:')
    regex = r'[x][A-Za-z]{6,6}'
    sigMatch = re.match(regex,usrname)      --> username & pattern matching
    sigMatch.group()

except AttributeError:
    print "Kindly enter your name"
    raise AttributeError

   [...]
```

Immediately I'm doing SSH from HUB1 as below:

```
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.connect('100.103.113.15', username='', password='')
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command("cd /home/dir;ls -lrt")
```

By doing ssh from HUB1, I can virtually login into HUB2 and copy file in 
desired directory [ i,e though I run my script in H1 via SSH I can pass 
control to HUB2 and execute commands in H2 and able to do desired 
operations]

Now, Challenge has come away:

Now I need to copy the same file from HUB2 to HUB3 [which I had copied from 
Hub1] by running the same script in Hub1 it self.So,I did scp in SSH as below:

```
ssh_stdin,ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command("scp %s 
usrname@112.186.104.7:/home/dir/ABCdir" %(imageName))
```

Here It has to prompt for user input for password like **Please enter your 
password**, but above command is directing prompt statement to **ssh_stderr** 
channel. Because of this I'm not able to successfully copy a file when I 
execute scp in ssh.exec_command("").

Points to remember:

1. I don't want to Run two scripts one in H1 and another in H2(for scp) ---> ruled out
2. My intention is to copy a file from h1 -> h2 -> h3 which are independent each other.

I followed above procedure and In addition to this I tried couple of methods

1. adding unknown_host_key [by doing this in ,out & err channels are open but file transfer doesn't occur]
2. By invoking another script in HUB2 [I'm able to invoke scripts which does not require user input but my purpose is to give user input. So not able to trigger another script here].

I request to provide possible ways to nullify the above problem.

Comment: Have you considered public key authentication with SSH, maybe with agent forwarding?

Comment: What errors you can see?

Comment: "Please enter your password " should be directed to ssh_stdin channel but    I'm seeing same statement in ssh_stderr channel because of this I'm not able to provide input. other than this there is no errors

Comment: @KlausD. I'm not sure how to consider this public key authentication while performing SSH using python. Any further hints that I can try this programatically ?

Comment: LMGTFY: https://kb.iu.edu/d/aews https://gist.github.com/batok/2352501

Comment: Plus one. A question tagged with SCP that actually involves code!